# How to Count The most common multiple event is SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

in my question i meant to something like this:

```
Username Favorite    
Josef    6
Bonni    5
Etc      5
```

After doing something ill get answer which is 5 because it showed up more times then the 6.

Please help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by`:

```
select favorite
from t
group by favorite
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

This is ANSI-standard sequence.  Different databases have different ways of expressing the `fetch first` clause.

In MS Access, this would be:

```
select top (1) favorite
from t
group by favorite
order by count(*) desc, username;
```

The inclusion of `username` is to be sure that you only get one row in the event of ties.

Comment: well, im using c# tho, a translate to c# would help :) and im using access

Comment: @OBZ . . . If you have a C# question, you should ask *another* question and tag it appropriately.  This question is clearly about SQL (and you should not change this one because it has been answered).